# How does the increment operator (++) work on DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, operator-overloading

What happens if you use the [increment operator (++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36x43w8w.aspx) on a DateTime type in C#?

For instance, if I did this:

```
DateTime blah = new DateTime(2010, 12, 24);

blah++;
```

What does blah become?  Does that increment by a tick or a day?

Or is that even legal?

I don't have a dev environment around, and won't for a few days, or I would just try it and find out.  I was too curious to wait so I figured I'd ask the community.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not valid:

> Error 1 Operator '++' cannot be
>   applied to operand of type
>   'System.DateTime'

Comment: Really?  Oh.  Stupid question I guess.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime_methods.aspx) Methods from msdn documentation.

If you don't have Visual Studio now and if you have high speed internet, then try out [MSDN Virtual Labs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/aa570323).